# How can I extend a library's decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I would like to extend a library's decorator.  I know that I can just call both decorators:

```
@my_decorator
@lib_decorator
def func():
    pass
```

But I would like to avoid having to pass `@lib_decorator` to each function each time.  I would like my decorator to automatically decorate `func()` with `lib_decorator`.  How can I do this?  Can they be nested?

Answer (score 17):

You can incorporate the lib's decorator within yours. For simple, argument-less decorators, it's rather straight-forward:

```
def my_decorator():
    @lib_decorator  # <--- Just include the lib's decorator here
    def inner:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

---

It's a bit trickier for decorators that have arguments.  Just remember that your decorator is replacing the decorated function with the inner-most function. So that's the one you need to decorate.  So if you call your decorator with args, e.g.

```
@my_decorator(arg)
def func():
    pass
```

Then decorate the inner function with the lib decorator:

```
def my_decorator(arg):
    def wrapper(func):

        @lib_decorator  # <--- Just include the lib's decorator here
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return wrapper
```

Or, using the `class` form of the decorator function:

```
class my_decorator():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        pass

    def __call__(self, func):
        @lib_decorator  # <--- Just include the lib's decorator here
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner
```

Comment: Both of your example decorators have an extra layer that is only necessary if you want to support passing arguments to the decorator (e.g. `@my_decorator("foo")`). For decorators like the ones in the question that are not being called by the user (just named, e.g. `@my_decorator`), you don't need that layer.

Comment: Thanks, @Blckknght. I believe my example decorators are suited for when the *function* requires arguments, not the *decorator* (e.g., `func("foo")`, no?  Either way I admit it isn't needed for the example in the question, I was just trying to provide the most complete solution in case it was relevant to anyone else.

Comment: Yeah, they support functions that take arguments, but what I'm, talking about is that `@my_decorator` won't work to apply them. Because of the extra layer, you need `@my_decorator()` (calling the decorator factory, which returns the decorator, which the `@` syntax calls on the function, returning the inner wrapped function). If you go rid of `wrapper` in your function version, it would work without the parentheses. The class version is a bit trickier, since not all decorators play nice with methods. You'd probably want `__call__` to do `return lib_decorator(self.func)(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: @Blckknght, thanks. This helped make things much more clear for me.  I hadn't caught the distinction between `@my_decorator` and `@my_decorator()` in all of my reading before.

Comment: How does `arg` get passed to the `lib_decorator`?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily transform a decoration like yours:

```
@my_decorator
@lib_decorator
def func():
    pass
```

To this simpler decoration, using function composition:

```
my_composed_decorator = lambda func: my_decorator(lib_decorator(func))

@my_composed_decorator
def func():
    pass
```

Comment: I love the function composition approach you showed as it recalls that decorators are indeed function returning functions which can be treated as such without having to use the `@something` sugar.